# Cancelling and rerunning update statistics in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

what happens if we cancel a update statistics with fullscan query for a table midway? Does it rollback all updates? Or does it keep the stats that have already been updated and the ones that haven't been updated use the original stats?

And if it keeps the updates partially, what happens we immediately run the query for same table again?

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
EXEC sys.sp_helptext 
    @objname = N'sys.sp_updatestats'
```

you can see what the update stats job is doing under the hood.

If you cancel it halfway through a batch then the stats that it has already updated will remain, any it hasn't touched wont change. It wont rollback if its half way through one it just wont update.

Comment: Thanks. So What would happen If i immidiately ran the update stats again on the same table? Does it pickup where it left?

Comment: I think it will start again because it's hasn't updated anything when you cancel it

Comment: Your first post says that it does update even if cancelled halfway through.

Comment: No it doesn't, it says it you cancel half way through a table  it won't rollback. If you do multiple tables then and cancel it half way through it will update the ones it has completed but any it hasn't touched wont update or the table it is currently working on it won't update